# Can't compile an AspectJ Aspect with @DeclareMixin

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I'm experimenting AspectJ's `@DeclareMixin` feature, but I keep getting this error:

> /media/thomas/data-disk/sandbox/java/aspectj-tests/src/main/java/org/myproject/aspects/MyAspect.java:7:0::0 Method 'org.myproject.aspects.MyInterface org.myproject.aspects.MyAspect.declareStuff()': factory method does not return something that implements 'org.myproject.aspects.MyInterface'

Here's my aspect:

```
package org.myproject.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclareMixin;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect
{
    @DeclareMixin(value = "@org.myproject.aspects.Marker *",
            interfaces = MyInterface.class)
    public MyInterface declareStuff()
    {
        return new MyImplementation();
    }
}
```

Here's the annotation:

```
package org.myproject.aspects;

public @interface Marker
{
}
```

Here's the interface:

```
package org.myproject.aspects;

public interface MyInterface
{
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Here's the implementation:

```
package org.myproject.aspects;

public class MyImplementation implements MyInterface
{
    @Override
    public void doSomething()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

Here's the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aspectj-tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <aspectj-version>1.7.4</aspectj-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it works if I remove the `interfaces` element from the `@DeclareMixin` annotation.